# Association named was not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I am working in Rails 2. I have three tables: `users`, `lms_users` and `group_details`.

In `lms_users` id from `users` and `group_details` is coming as foreign keys. `lms_users` has its own attributes as well. I am unable to define association in their respective models. I tried this:

In the `LmsUser` model

```
belongs_to :users
belongs_to :group_details
```

In the `User` model

```
has_many :group_details , :through => :lms_users
```

In the `GroupDetail` model

```
has_many :users , :through => :lms_users
```

But I am getting this error

```
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError in Lms usersController#index
Association named 'lms_user' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the association you're going through as a has_many.

So for example, your user.rb should look like this:

```
has_many :lms_users
has_many :group_details , :through => :lms_users
```

And your group_detail.rb should contain the following:

```
has_many :lms_users
has_many :users , :through => :lms_users
```

:through goes through an association, so the association needs to already be set up.

Comment: In addition to @cheeseweasel answer, one change should be there in LmsUser model the associations should be `belongs_to :user` instead of users and `belongs_to :group_detail` instead of group_details

Comment: How can i access the data in lms_users table coloum through resultset variable?